# Accessing Jupyter from a user other than root user

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, restricted-access

When I'm logged in as root user to a remote Linux server I'm able to run the command:

```
jupyter-notebook --no-browser --port=8909 --allow-root
```

When I run  `which jupyter` I get:

```
/usr/local/anaconda3/bin/jupyter
```

and `env | grep ^PATH` gives:

```
PATH=/usr/local/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

Now, if the run the same `which jupyter` command with a user who doesn't have `sudo` access I get:

```
/usr/bin/which: no jupyter in (/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/mook01/.local/bin:/home/mook01/bin)
```

and `env | grep ^PATH` gives:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/mook01/.local/bin:/home/mook01/bin
```

My question is how can I enable this `mook01` user to access the `jupyter` command without giving them `sudo` access?

Comment: Hello. Sounds like this would be a good question for the Jupyter Project people. https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by prepending the `anaconda3` directories in the `PATH` environment variable as the `mook01` user:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/anaconda3/condabin:$PATH
```

That would allow the shell commands to look under the aforementioned paths in order to find the `jupyter` executable.

Read more about `_PATH_`: https://tldp.org/HOWTO/pdf/Path.pdf

To make the change persistent, you have to add the `export` line to the `~/.bashrc` file of the corresponding user so that it gets sourced upon the start of every shell session.